# 'A' vs 'An' ufotable Production

Tags: word-choice, grammar, determiners

The company ofutable (pronounced UFO-table) likes to start their movies with a black background, and

> An ufotable Production

emblazoned in the middle of the screen.

As a native english speaker, I find this phrase rather jarring.  It seems grammatically incorrect.

I'm confident it should be:

> A ufotable Production

Why?

Comment: Do you know how the company pronounces "Ufotable"?

Comment: If the company name is pronounced 'yoo-foe-table' or 'yoo-eff-owe-table', then it would be "A ufotable Production". If it's pronounced 'eww-foe-table', then it would be as given in the question.

Comment: Yes, it's ***a uniform*** but ***an umlaut***   How is ufotable pronounced?

Comment: If it's *an ufotable,* then it must start /ˈʊfoʊ/ rather than /ˈjʊfoʊ/.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: It's a Japanese animation studio. I don't think you can infer much about what the English pronunciation must be like from a spelling choice that could have been made by someone who might not even speak English very well. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ufotable) says the name is pronounced in Japanese as *yūfōtēburu* which would correspond to English /jufoʊteɪbl̩/.

Comment: @sumelic If that's the case, then it is not "an ufotable". My comment stands: **if** it is "an ufotable", then there is only one way of pronouncing it.